# Ionic app REST response data not showing correctly iOS, Android works

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 app for Android and iOS.
The app uses an API to get data from the server.
This works for Android, but for iOS I don't get the view updated with the response of the server.

.ts file

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.rest.get(this.url).subscribe(res => {
        this.profile = res['profile'];
        this.statistics = res['statistics'];
    });
}
```

provider

```
return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/${resource}`, {'params': param})
        .map(response => response);
```

.html

```
<ion-row class="stats" padding-horizontal="">
    <ion-col col-6>Friends</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6 text-right>{{statistics?.friends}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-row class="stats" padding-horizontal="">
    <ion-col col-6>Achievements</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6 text-right>{{statistics?.achievements}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

in Android the stats are nicely updated, but on iOS it stays blank except the fixed text, that is shown.

But when we go to a subpage and then use the back button or open and close the menu, we get the data visible (see attached screenshot).

Ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.4
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 11 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Android\android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: hi @PostMans, did u find any solution for that issue, thanks

Comment: @greenridinghood: Unfortunaly no :0 And because Ionic 4 was released short after I (re)created the app in Ionic 4 which is almost done. The Ionic 4 app is working in Android, I will test iOS soon. But you experience the same ?

Comment: yes @PostMans , I mean Android developer from my team dont have any issue, but I dont see correct data. I found some ideas from other forums/site such as git, they were talking about Angular CLI need to update or something. Looks like that helped me, but now my app stacking at splash screen I build successfully. I am not sure maybe I should not update Angular CLI, who knows :) I am soo new to ionic

Comment: @greenridinghood : About the splash screen, did you have the in the config `AutohideSplashScreen = false` and `SplashScreenDelay = 30000` and in the app.component.ts when the app is initialized (initializeApp) the line `this.splashScreen.hide();`

Comment: ,yes i have in my config these name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false", name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000", and name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" . my app not stuck at splash anymore, i just have little long white screen after splash, thanks